# How Can I Compile Code With ACE

Tags: ace-editor

I will use online compiler which is ACE https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about i can put the editor but i dont know how to compile and get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ace is an editor, not a compiler you can't use it to compile code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [hackerrank api](https://market.mashape.com/hackerrank/hackerrank) view the documentation for more info to enable one to choose different languages to compile.